# To fill a column following one condition (when cell is empty)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find out how to fill a cell ***on the next empty row***, using a loop.

I learned how to loop through a range, and how to fill cells conditionally, for example:

```
Dim column As Range: Set column = Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns(1)
    For Each cell In column.Cells
        If cell.Value >= 0 Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Positive"
        ElseIf cell.Value < 0 Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Negative"
        End If
    Next
```

However, my current task is a bit more complex, and I do not know how to solve a particular issue. I have **two sheets**,  **one in each workbook**. **If**, when looping through a column in the first workbook, I find an **empty cell**, then the **value** in the cell that is 0,1 **offset** to it should be **copied** to a column in the **second workbook**.

My objective is thus that the second workbook contains a tidy column, with one value after the other row by row. The first workbook remains unchanged.

The particular issue is that I can't find what the exact syntax or condition to tell Excel to fill a cell on the first empty row that it finds.

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("QuartalReport.xlsm")
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
Dim column As Range: Set column = ws.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns(1) 'some cells in this column are empty

Dim wb2 As Workbook: Set wb2 = Workbooks("ClientList.xlsm")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets(1)
Dim column2 As Range: Set column = ws2.Sheets(1).Columns(3) 'this column will be filled as the macro is used each time

For Each cell In column.Cells

If cell.Value = "" Then
???
```

*Edited for clarification:*

This code will go in the first workbook (`"QuartalReport.xlsm"`). Both workbooks have only one sheet.

The data in the first workbook has no table formatting, and it starts in row 3.

The data in the second workbook should begin with cell `C2` (or any column in row 2), as the first row will be for the header (though like in the first workbook, it is unformatted). Save for this column, the worksheet will be empty.

The objective is to copy the value in the cell in column B of the first workbook if the cell in the same row in column A is empty. For example if cells `A3` through `A5` in `"QuartalReport.xlsm` contain values, the rows should altogether be skipped. But if `A6` is blank, then the value of whatever is in `B6` should be copied to the next empty row (being the first case, `C2`) in `"ClientList.xlsm"`. If the next empty cell is in `A12`, then `B12` should be copied to `C3`. As such the column in the second workbook will have no empty rows between data.

Comment: In which workbook is this code located? It is safer to use the worksheet names instead of their indexes. Is the data in the first worksheet in table format i.e. does it have a row of headers i.e. in which row does the data start? Are you copying the value from the same row in column B if the cell in column A is blank? In the 2nd worksheet, where do you want to put the data e.g. after the last non-empty cell in column C or starting with cell C2 or something else? Please clarify, best by editing [your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74992778/edit).

Comment: Hello @VBasic2008, thanks for taking the time to read my question. I edited it so as to include the missing details. Please let me know if I did it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A VBA Lookup: Copy Matches Consecutively

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyMatchesConsecutively()
    
    ' Reference the source range ('srg').
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim sfrrg As Range: Set sfrrg = sws.Range("A3:B3") ' first row range
    
    Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long
    
    With sfrrg
        ' '.Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)' is 'A3:B1048576' (or 'A3:B65536')
        Dim slCell As Range: Set slCell = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If slCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
        srCount = slCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    ' Write the values from the source range to an array ('Data').
    
    Dim Data(): Data = srg.Value
    
    ' Write the results to the top of the first column of the array.
    
    Dim sr As Long, dr As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        If IsEmpty(Data(sr, 1)) Then ' empty
        ' Or:
        'If Len(CStr(Data(sr, 1))) = 0 Then ' blank e.g. '=""' (includes empty)
            dr = dr + 1
            Data(dr, 1) = Data(sr, 2)
        End If
    Next sr
    ' The results are in the rows from 1 to 'dr' of the first column.
    
    ' Reference the destination range ('drg').
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks("ClientList.xlsm")
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range("C2")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(dr) ' single-column of size 'dr'
    
    ' Write the results to the destination range.
    
    drg.Value = Data ' write
    drg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear ' clear below

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Matches copied consecutively.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you lots - it works perfectly, and I was able to use it and make small changes for other similar tasks thanks to the comments. I'm wondering - If I had another column C in `QuartalReport`, and its value would have to be copied to a D column in `ClientList` (right next to C) under the same criteria, would that be possible? I imagine the solution lies in this specific line `Data(dr, 1) = Data(sr, 2)` but I can't figure out how to change it accordingly so it fits more than one column. Does it make more sense to just repeat the process with different constants?